# wialon, new login mechanizm

Tags: java, url

Connection output Stream code :

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/oauth.html");
String data = encode("client_id") + "=" + encode("GarageGPSLocal");
data += "&" + encode("redirect_uri") + "=" + encode("http://localhost:8084/Wialon/Servlet");
data += "&" + encode("access_type") + "=" + encode("0x100");
data += "&" + encode("activation_time") + "=" + encode("0");
data += "&" + encode("duration") + "=" + encode("2592000");
data += "&" + encode("flags") + "=" + encode("6");
data += "&" + encode("login") + "=" + encode("demo");
data += "&" + encode("passw") + "=" + encode("demo");

URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
writer.write(data);
writer.flush();

setBufferedReader(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())));
this.sessionId = loginToken(reader.readLine());
```

servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    int svc_error = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("svc_error"));

    if (svc_error != 0) {
        response.getWriter().println("Svc_error: " + request.getParameter("svc_error"));
        response.getWriter().flush();
        return;
    }

    response.getWriter().println(request.getParameter("access_token"));
    response.getWriter().flush();
}
```

is there any way to catch from get['access_token'] without servlet ? what to write to parameter redirect_uri ??

Answer (score 2):

You can't generate token with such method. It is allowed to generate token only using native Wialon form http://example.com/login.html.
This vulnerability was fixed a few weeks ago.